# Regex - URL with a specific beginning and end with something in the middle

Tags: regex

I'd like to select all strings (parts of URLs) with a "/en" at the beginning, then a random string in the middle and at the end a "aspx", e.g. "/en/about-us-or/any-other-string-12345/page.aspx"

Here's my current approach.

```
^/en.*aspx$
```

- `^/en` -- at the beginning a "/en"
- `.*` -- then a random string in the middle
- `aspx$` -- and a aspx at the end

I wonder why it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What do you get? And what software is running this regex?

Comment: According to my sources (http://regexhero.net/tester/) it works. The problem might be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your input strings are complete URIs (like this: "http://www.example.com/en/about-us-or/any-other-string-12345/page.aspx").

If so, your regex will fail because the ^ flag matches the beginning of a string, which in this case is right before the h in http.

The $ character will also cause the regex to fail on URIs that look like this "http://www.example.com/en/about-us-or/any-other-string-12345/page.aspx?parameter=value".

Edit:
To actually **answer** to your question - try dropping the ^ and $ from your regex: `/en.*aspx`

Answer (score 0):

the / character has a special meaning in regex -- so you will have to escape it (\/) also group the dot-star (.*) :

```
^\/en(.*)aspx$
```

Comment: The above works with Java and JavaScript Regex engines. what language/engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are using this as part of a `.htaccess` rewrite rule. The URL-path  presented to [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) is on a per-directory basis and will never have an initial `/` (it is stripped). Try removing the initial `/` from your pattern like so:

```
^en/(.*)\.aspx$
```